# How do I provide a link to a comment in a StackOverflow post?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Direct Link to a Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment)

How can I construct a link to a comment in one of my posts?

Comment: Can we please have the feature-request tag added to this?

Comment: Direct comment links exist but should be more intuitive, e.g. having permalink icon - see
[Improve the usability/intuitiveness of direct comment links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280567)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you will be able to do is link to an answer that the comment is on. You can find a link's url by looking at the LINK flag underneath the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. The best you can do is link to the question or answer the comment is on, and perhaps add the user's name to add direction for followers of the link.

Comment: How to link to answers?

Comment: Each answer has a link button under the text of the post.