# Where does this comment link come from?

Tags: discussion, comments, hyperlinks

Check out this link. (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/18113/comments?_=1252601104250#comment-36330)

Where on earth does it come from? Or is it a hidden link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the actual URL that would be fetched via an XMLHttpRequest when you click the "show *n* more comments" link. The page JavaScript merely takes the resulting HTML and stuffs it into the page, replacing the existing comments with the full set.

This particular URL has been modified slightly, adding a fragment so as to jump to a specific comment (the one with the id `comment-36330`) - of course, you'll need a fairly small browser window to actually *see* this... presumably, whoever posted that link was just being a jackass.

Answer (score 1):

[SEModifications](http://rchern.github.com/StackExchangeScripts/#install), an userscript for StackExchange sites, adds a permalink to every comment. This way, they can be linked to very easily.

Comment: This question was posted way before that script was created.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that.

Comment: However, such permalinks [might simply not work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment/27319#27319) when the comment is somehow hidden (or has been deleted), and then leave the user on top of the page, oblivious about what to look for. The problem with hidden comments would be solved with [Auto expand comments of specific answer when browsing directly to that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71182/auto-expand-comments-of-specific-answer-when-browsing-directly-to-that-answer). But even then deleted comments will *silently* break the permalink.

Comment: no reason to be sorry.  I was just pointing out that this answer couldn't possibly be the answer to the question.