# Auto expand comments of specific answer when browsing directly to that answer

Tags: feature-request, comments

When I browse to a specific answer and it has more than five comments, I would like the comments to become expanded automatically instead of having to click the "add/show [x] more comments" - after all, I'm browsing to this specific answer so naturally I would like to see all comments made on it.

For example:
[How to access a Div inside a repeater using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4303668/how-to-access-a-div-inside-a-repeater-using-javascript/4304261#4304261)

Comment: +1, as that would also allow for [direct links to comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment/27319#27319)...

Comment: Nice, Nick [is promising upcoming changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94486/comment-links-on-responses-tab-do-not-work-correctly-when-the-comment-is-hidden/107511#107511)...

Answer (score 5):

The activity overview currently [links to specific comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood?tab=activity#apage_1-afilter_comments), for comments on answers. The scrolling relies on `#comment-xx` URL fragments, and [fails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86165/should-we-require-minimum-reputation-to-continue-asking-questions/86222#comment-212750) if the comment is initially hidden, bringing one to the top of the page instead.

<s>So, I could either file a bug report for the confusing links, or give this feature request some more attention. Bump! :-)</s> (This has meanwhile been [reported as a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94486/comment-links-on-responses-tab-do-not-work-correctly-when-the-comment-is-hidden).)

Implementing auto-expanding will still make `#comment-xx`-links fail if a comment has been deleted, again bringing one to the top of the page rather than to the answer. To gracefully fall back to scrolling to the answer then, some client-side JavaScript-fu would be needed to first see if the comment still exists, and rewrite the fragment if not? If such script is ever considered:

- The same JavaScript might be used to [show a warning when following a permalink to a deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88589/show-warning-or-404-when-following-permalink-to-deleted-answer)?
- The same JavaScript might be used for questions, if only to use it for [direct links to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment/27319#27319). For questions the comments surely should only expand if the URL has a `#comment-xx` fragment. Such cannot be handled server-side, so surely needs some JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the bump of confidence, as I don't see much activity here I would submit bug report regarding the inbox comments sending to the top of the page. :)

Comment: But then, @Shadow, if the quick solution is to remove the URL fragments, browsing one's own activity when searching for something might become a bit more difficult. Hmmm, tough decision, not even knowing if a bug report would be fixed ;-)

Comment: I would love to see all comments auto-expanded (or have a preference that would let me set it for my account.) The More link is a pale gray, and if the page is busy (i.e. there's another answer immediately below a list of comments for one answer) it's sometimes easy to miss that there IS a More link.