# View all comments from the beginning (on page load)?

Tags: feature-request, comments

When a question / answer on SO has more than 5 comments, the additional comments are hidden on page load. One has to click on the "add / show X more comments" link to display them.

Since I have a very high screen height (1200px), I would like it more if all the comments were visible from the beginning. I don't mind scrolling that much.

Is there something that can be done to make the comments visible from the beginning?
Otherwise, this is a feature request.

Comment: What I find annoying is the that it doesn't show the first 5, it shows some,which I assume are in order, read them (sometimes they don't make sense) and then expand and re-read

Comment: @Trufa It shows the first five by default unless there are upvoted comments. At which point, it prioritizes by the top 5 rated comments, ordered by their chronological sorting.

Comment: @Grace Note, Thank you! I had never understood what was it doing, I still find this annoying :) but at least it makes a little more sense.

Comment: For *a single*, specific answer: [Auto expand comments of specific answer when browsing directly to that answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71182/auto-expand-comments-of-specific-answer-when-browsing-directly-to-that-answer). (Yes, please!)

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/308426/when-revealing-hidden-comments-focus-now-goes-to-the-first-newly-revealed-comme  (as this FR might be part of a possible future workaround).