# Page title from First url in comment is used for title text of all additional urls

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

I put two [separate links in a single comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002940/json-and-circular-reference-exception/2003210#2003210) and noticed a bug with the title text when hovering over the second URL. It has the first URLs title text.

[Screen Shot of Issue http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3352/sametitleincomment.png](http://img189.imageshack.us/img189/3352/sametitleincomment.png)

Screenshot added because it's not possible to [link directly to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment).

Comment: upvoted for freehand kinda-circles!

Comment: MS Paint for the win!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would only affect downstream links that did not themselves have a title, but fixed.

Comment: Jeff, maybe I don't understand the fix you put in place but in the comment used as an example above the second link now has no title at all? Was that the intended behavior?

Comment: @ahsteele, it is [by-design] only internal SO links get titles .. but we are looking at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/inline-links-in-comments

Comment: Cool, thank you for following up!