# Inline links in comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, hyperlinks

Can we *please* have these?

I would like to be able to write something like `[Inline Link](http://example.com/)` and have it work in a comment instead of "Inline Link - http://example.com/".

Case in point (not my comment):

[image: Long link]

Doesn't that look smashing?

Comment: If you need to put that much information, why doesn't a full-fledged answer work for you?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6407/allow-html-tags-in-comments

Comment: random: Because many comments are not answers.

Comment: [Yeah Thats Sooooo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/inline-links-in-comments "Nothing here!") Cooooooool!

Comment: [So this is done?](http://superuser.com/questions/127349/continue-process-after-closing-terminal-closed) Yes!

Comment: [hella good!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtTj4cramPM)

Comment: I gave up on this a long time ago and haven't check back until now. This is great. Thanks, guys :)

Comment: [Inline Link](http://foo.com)

Comment: It's **heavily annoying** that comment link markdown is different than post link markdown !!

Comment: [I have to try this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/inline-links-in-comments)

Comment: Is there any way to link to other answers with fragment URLs?  E.g. [this question's accepted answer](#37761).

Comment: @opello That would be assuming that other answers are present on the same page. Which need not be the case when there are many answers, or when a post is exported from SE and imported into software that shows posts in a  different way. Introducing a feature to make links more fragile is not a good idea.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier Ah, that makes sense.  So would a best practice be to just use the 'share' link?  My goal was obviously not fragility, it just seemed bad form to redirect if the content was already loaded.

Comment: Now that is solved can you @AlexBudovski change [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/169185/282658) to the accepted answer?

Comment: @Persijn Done. <padding>

Comment: Does anyone know why this change didn't retroactively render old comments following the appropriate syntax as hyperlinks? E.g. see the [first comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4437527/1858225).

Comment: @JourneymanGeek ROFL glad to see you're on it already!  The bug triggers when the href part doesn't contain a schema and you go back and edit it after.  It also triggered a few times just editing a post with an inline link, but you've spotted that already!

Comment: I was gonna answer that XD. And I was curious! I'm not sure if its a bug, or a quirk of the comment markdown dialect (and Its not my job to find out, I'm just a mod) but its the space...

Comment: [Inline Link](http://foo.com) It works. Learned new stuff 2day

Comment: Related *[Add data.SE style "magic links" to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments/94000#94000)* (covers magic links in both questions/answers, comments, and chat).

Answer (score 362, accepted):

Looks like this was added. You do it just as described in the question:

`[Inline Link](http://foo.com)`

Comment: Make sure there are no spaces between the closing ] and opening ( though.

Comment: if your link comment like this `[ Inline Link](http://foo.com)` , this will give you error because you have space  near on the bracket,you have to remove those space to avoid error link comment

Comment: Note: the "http://" part is mandatory. You can't just put a shortened URL like "foo.com/bar".

Answer (score 42):

I think this should be allowed. If you can add links (and you can), why can't you give them meaningful names?

Take Æther's post as an example, he could have just said "[related proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6407/allow-html-tags-in-comments)". Looks much better.

Comment: I got the `Insight` badge for this... Good since my answer was very insightful

Answer (score 12):

I know I've wished for this feature a number of times, for adding a link to someone else's answer. Particularly because it was a comment to someone else's answer, it wasn't appropriate to add a separate answer.

Comments should generally be short—true. I think allowing this feature would make comments shorter and more readable.

The comment length limit should still be a valid incentive for people to keep comments short (I assume the links would continue to "use up" the comment length limit).

Comment: yes, shorter and more readable is always an excellent goal -- implemented!

Comment: Nice Amswer, and glad you guys championed this.