# Automatic 'possible duplicate' comments should use new inline comment syntax

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, automatic-comments

Now that links can be [added into comments inline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/inline-links-in-comments), this should be done with the [automatic 'possible duplicate' comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate/44529) added when a vote to close is made. It would make sense to place the question title in the comment, instead of the link.

e.g., instead of

```
possible duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/216819/…
```

have

```
possible duplicate of [How does a debugger work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216819/how-does-a-debugger-work)
```

which should render as

possible duplicate of [How does a debugger work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216819/how-does-a-debugger-work)

Comment: I imagine it's simply "possible duplicate of: [qTitle](qLink)"

Comment: Even more, I thought those auto-comments triggered the implementation of the inline links. (4th comment [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44173/autocomment-when-voting-to-close-as-duplicate/44529#44529))

Comment: No uppercase P in "Possible" then?

Comment: @Arjan: I would definitely prefer an uppercase P, but there isn't one at the moment.

Comment: @Arjan Actually, the uppercase P was [declined](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44528/capitalize-possible-in-the-automatically-inserted-comments-when-you-vote-to-clo)

Comment: Yup, and given [The Threat Of The Giant S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/new-users-cant-create-new-tags-show-a-singular-or-plural-message/9694#9694) I wouldn't dare bringing it to Jeff's attention again ;-)

Comment: _P_ossible duplicate, please

Comment: @Kop: **P** ossible duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

I like that idea since it provides a <strike>*slightly*</strike> better looking link. <strike>The only problem is when/if the title changes. Should the system then go through and change all comments that happen to reference it?</strike>

Comment: I don't think the "Possible Duplicate:" header at the top updates if the source post is renamed. Likewise, comments aren't updated to match @username changes. So it doesn't seem all that necessary to update the title, especially since unlike my examples, the 'possible duplicate' comment is very ephemeral.

Comment: @ccornet Good point. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just giving you an answer that this is now implemented as can be witnessed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49297/usernames-dont-seem-to-handle-utf-8-characters-well) in the comments