# Auto-replace SOFU links with their title

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title)

It seems pretty useless in comments to read "have a look at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/question/number/..." and just where the title might start it will be replaced by an ellipsis. Why not have the link be replaced? I know hovering the link shows the title, but since the only information provided by the link is about to which SOFU-site it is, the URL itself seems pretty useless to me. Additionally, the title might be prepended with a small [SO] etc tag.

Comment: This sits square between [this request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title), which targets all internal links in the post body as well, and [this implemented request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49182/automatic-possible-duplicate-comments-should-use-new-inline-comment-syntax), which targeted just automatically generated comments by the duplication closing process.

Comment: @Grace Note: I didn't mention the post body since the links there don't suffer from ellipsis. But since that request is there already (thanks for the link) and mine is just a subset, I'll vote to close as dupe