# Make links to other questions display better in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments)

Often I type a comment like “see also …” with a link to another question on the same site.  The link is not formatted very nicely.

I would like to see

> [Why does restarting a computer fix things?](https://superuser.com/questions/2467/why-does-restarting-a-computer-fix-things)

Automatically replaced with

> “[Why do I need restart computer after installing new software](https://superuser.com/questions/2467/why-does-restarting-a-computer-fix-things)?”

in the comment, when the comment is displayed.   This should also cope when the title of the linked question being changed.

When this link is to another server exchange site, it could be formatted like:

> SiteName:Question Title

Comment: or (at least for the post-beta sites) the logo in front of the question

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56364/auto-replace-sofu-links-with-their-title "It's about comments specifically"), which was closed by the author as a dupe of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title "It's about all forms of linking, including comments").

Comment: @Grace Note: oh, *that*'s why the idea sounded so great to me... How can you remember all those things and I'm having trouble remembering my own feature-request?

Comment: Also, wow, tooltips?  Fancy.

Comment: This may have been implemented in _Posts_, but this is requesting that it be implemented in _Comments_. I would love to see this done for comments as well.

Comment: Blocked by the bounty, but see [Replace links with the current question title in comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394)

Comment: @AlEverett You may have already seen it, but I do [have a userscript for this](http://stackapps.com/questions/2378/comment-link-autoprettifier) if you want this functionality right now.

Comment: @Tim: Seen it. Downloaded it. Used it. Loved it. Still think it should be built-in, thought.