# Replace links with the current question title in comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, hyperlinks, internal-links

In questions, links get converted into question titles (see [Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title))

Can the same functionality be added to comments?

Comment: For example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title could be replaced with the title the same as in the question text.

Comment: I (personally) don't think that's is necessary and think [this is enough](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title) fot comments, titles would be to spacey for comments, I don't know, I'm not donwn-voting though!

Comment: (Just for the "Linked" section: this was also part of [Can we improve the automatic titling of links to internal URLs?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80543/can-we-improve-the-automatic-titling-of-links-to-internal-urls))

Comment: This is a duplicate of an old [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16609/feature-request-when-posting-links-to-same-site-in-comment-display-question-text)

Comment: Link to user script to do this, generated via said user script - [SE Comment Link Helper](http://stackapps.com/q/2378)

Comment: [Another userscript that can potentially help with this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296653/230261), adds markdown links to share dialog.

Answer (score 111):

This would be especially useful on **mobile devices**, where:

- Cutting and pasting the title of a question and then its URL is a huge pain, because it involves switching back and forth between the comment page and the page with the question to be linked, without the aid of windows or tabs.
- Have you ever tried editing Markdown on a mobile device? Moving the cursor and selecting bracket characters is not fun. And better get it right the first time, because clicking the edit button afterwards is even harder.
- Userscripts aren't available on mobile.

As for **[Jeff's objections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86909/351462)** why it *can't* be done:

- "Comments are processed on the fly." Look up the title once and add the Markdown that we would otherwise have to type manually. (If that ends up making the comment too long, there are lots of ways to handle it, the simplest of which is to only do the conversion when it will fit.)
- "If you want this, put your links in a post, where it is already supported." That's not a very good reason. You're basically arguing that we shouldn't even have comments.

  - Edit, *thirteen years later!*: I think maybe what Jeff meant is comments are meant to be ephemeral. Intentionally crippling comments is a feature, because it encourages us to incorporate feedback from comments into the post, as I am doing now.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree. I will often comment on my phone as well. There's no reason the transformation couldn't happen when the comment is first accepted.

Comment: commenting for me on my Android  only works with the [Hacker's Keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=de), which has up-and down arrows etc.

Comment: @DavidHarkness "There's no reason the transformation couldn't happen when the comment is first accepted."  There might be a length limit problem, but in that case the transformation could either be ignored or done nevertheless.

Comment: I think it's a _little_ more complicated with the question of how to deal with comment length limits (truncate? how much truncation is too much? what if there's literally no more room?). the simple answer to that would just be: truncate titles up to some fixed extent as long as there's room for it, and then leave the rest of the links untouched.

Comment: Thanks, @starball, see my edits to the post. Over a decade later, I think finally get it. :)

Answer (score -10):

I don't think full titles are all that useful in most cases.

We already have `[site.SE]` as a short-hand for a link to `http://site.stackexchange.com` (and the SOFU exceptions, of course). Therefore, I think a useful middle ground would be `[site.SE/(q|a)/ID]` which would become `[site.SE/ID](http://site.stackexchange.com/(q|a)/ID)`.

As an alternative (or in addition), translate `[text](site.SE/(q|a)/ID)` to `[text](http://site.stackexchange.com/(q|a)/ID)`.

Answer (score -11):

As a fast workaround, you can easily convert the question to a link by those steps:

Example URL:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148999/cross-site-question-parsing-for-question-urls-in-comments
```

1. Paste it into the commentbox
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><--</kbd> repeat until you marked the question part of the url `cross-site-question-parsing-for-question-urls-in-comments` that is not needed in the post.
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd>
4. type `)`
5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd><--</kbd> repeat to the beginning of the URL
6. type `[`<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>`](`

this will look like this:
[cross-site-question-parsing-for-question-urls-in-comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148999/)

whis is quite satisfying in a comment, and close to
[Cross-site question parsing for question URLs in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148999/)

(see also https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230991/188615)

Comment: Not all that satisfying IMO, and it costs valuable characters!

Answer (score -66):

No, because comments are processed on the fly. This means a page with 12 links would incur 12 additional database queries -- every time the page is loaded.

Comments are meant to be lightweight. If you want this, put your links in a post, where it is already supported.

Comment: Although I am also not really agree with the request, but api does allow vectorized requests, that would not really cost 12 database queries for 12 links, isn't it?

Comment: This could be cached, so the database hits should not be an issue.   Stop blaming the database when you mean "I don't think the value of X is worth the programming time"

Comment: @ian database queries are never free, no matter how clever we are. The fundamental issue is that comments are *always* processed on the fly, unlike posts which store both raw and cooked representations.

Comment: But why can't this be done in a static way? i.e. look up the title *once* when the comment gets created. Having to do this manually all the time is terribly cumbersome and time-consuming.

Comment: @Pekka You'd have to modify the raw comment content in that case, which would mean that trying to edit the comment afterward would show you something different than what you typed. That doesn't seem like the best solution.

Comment: @Tim but that could be solved by an alternative syntax, say a leading `!` in front of the link as a sign that you want it converted. This would be *really* helpful

Comment: @Pekka True, but you run the risk of going over the comment length limit by modifying the content in an automated way, which could cause issues. I'm sure it's doable anyway, but I can see why it might not be worth it. That said, gimme a few minutes for that userscript...

Comment: Just made a similar request at http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/comments-should-replace-html-links-with-title-as-is-the-case-in-question, and was told about this post. Although I understand the reasoning, they are still truncated and the left portion is displayed, so why not just display the trailing portion of the link, at least then there would be some meaningful info before mouse over.

Comment: @TimStone In the extraordinarily rare event that it would cause the comment length to overflow, just don't do the conversion.

Comment: @TimStone **Userscripts don't work on my iPhone**. Try adding a comment with a link to a question and its title, adding the markdown formatting by hand on a mobile device. It's not fun.

Comment: I've posted another answer addressing these objections.

Comment: Is this the similar problem with this: [Expand links to Stack Exchange questions to show titles in chat when starred](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152744/175002)?

Comment: Okay, so the current implementation makes this difficult. Why not change the implementation then? Store "raw and cooked" representations of the comments.