# Resolve cross-site links to question title

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, site-crossover

When I post a link to another post on the same site, it resolves the link to the question title. When I post a link to Stack Overflow from Database Administrators, cross site, it doesn't.

I know I could make it a proper link and all that, but <strike>I'm lazy</strike> I do like the automatic resolution of links. Would it be possible, or is it [a problem like in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394/27535)?

I note intra-site is here but no mention (OK, one comment) for cross-site: [Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title)

Edit, 14 Nov 2011: any comment by the management?

Comment: I think there is just a difference between links in questions/answers (where it works) versus links in comments (where it doesn't).

Comment: @Paŭlo Eberman: Example of DBA.SE to SO in an answer: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6502/code-creates-different-plan-when-ran-ad-hoc-vs-in-a-stored-procedure/6503#6503 And SO to SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649701/should-i-use-a-unique-id-for-a-row-in-a-junction-table/7649809#7649809

Comment: This is already true on this very Meta, but not on other sites and other Metas it seems.

Comment: (As an aside: using the short referral links is no use [between the SE network sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/). So, you can drop the 27535. That doesn't fix the auto titles though.)

Comment: @Arjan:yep, but I'm too lazy to modify what I copy from the "link" link above :-) eg http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394/27535

Comment: @Arjan: an extra gnatschuffosecond saved! Excellent

Comment: any comment from the management?

Comment: The current implementation is explained in [What limitations does converting question links to links with titles have?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have/108475#108475)