# Automatically add question title when link is pasted in a comment

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments)

When a link to a question is pasted into another question, like so:

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title
```

The title of the question is automatically inserted, like so:

[Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title)

**It would be super useful if that also worked in comments.**