# Links to answers are not formatted to show the title automatically

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown

When including a link to a question in a post (question or answer) by copying the `Link` URL at the bottom of the question, the link is automatically formatted to appear as the question title:

For example, `https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/2552` becomes
[How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/2552)

With answers, this doesn't work:

For example, `https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2552` stays https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/39020/2552

However, when you click on that last link, the URL displayed in the browser window is much more verbose. Copying that link and using it in a post leads to the correct formatting:

For example, `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020` becomes [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020#39020), and the link correctly points to the answer.

Can we fix the behaviour of the short links to also be correctly formatted like the verbose ones?

Comment: @om-nom-nom: Apparently, this should work (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/69483#69483), since it's just an intra-site link. So shouldn't this be considered a bug?

Comment: No, it was not implemented: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments

Comment: My question isn't about comments, it's about one type of link in a post (question or answer) being converted properly, while another is not.

Comment: Indeed odd it still doesn't work, but balpha never responded to [a comment about that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have#108475).

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've misunderstood.

Comment: This really ought to be revisited. It's super weird UX: Given that the "share" link is *the* thing you use to get answer links, it doesn't make much sense for that to not be compatible with the title expansion.

Comment: I'm guessing this is by-design, since it's never been changed from the current behavior as far as I know. I'd probably suggest retagging this as a [feature-request] instead of a [bug].