# Expand links to Stack Exchange questions to show titles in chat when starred

Tags: feature-request, chat, hyperlinks

Sometimes someone posts a link to an important Meta discussion or another post from Stack exchange in chat. But it looks like this:
[image]

Visual aid added.

Internal links are already expanded, like so:

[Who are the two characters appearing in the background of superhero kids books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/21864/3804)

Why can't we do the same for things starred in chat?

<strike>Is this possible?</strike> Can we prioritise this?

Edit: Before Bounty runs out could we get official word/unofficial word on this? I mean even if it's 'Not any time soon' it'd be a little bit of closure.

Comment: I occasionally do this manually for starred posts by editing (go go gadget UX mod powers). It'd really be nice it were automatic

Comment: Everything is possible, it's matter of priorities.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Got it. Hows it looking now? :p

Comment: Nicely done, though I doubt that's what will help. But we can always hope! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this feature should be desirable and while I don't know if it should be considered a priority (the usefulness/gain is pretty restrict compared to some other more urgent tasks) I also think that probably the implementation effort should be small.

Anyway, I fear that the only ones that can give an actual answer to your question are staff member. As an user I can only support your request and give you my vote. Let's hope someone in the SE staff sees this question and post his opinion.