# Automatic titles for SO links in comments

Tags: discussion, comments, internal-links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments)

When I paste a link to an SO question into a comment, the resulting link title doesn't automatically change to the title of the question as it does in a regular post.

Is there a reason for that?

Has that features been requested before? I'm guessing it has, but I can't find it.