# Is there a process to reconsider a request that was status-declined four years ago?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, feature-request-process

I'm specifically interested in this request:

[Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments)

The feature was declined by some guy who now works for the Dark Side and his answer got downvoted into oblivion. My rebuttal has net 138 up votes.

**What's changed since the request was declined?**

1. I [answered the question with a rebuttal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116832/437) explaining what merits reconsideration.
2. A bunch of people upvoted my answer and downvoted Jeff's.
3. No moderator or Stack Exchange employee has responded in 5 years.

Do I really need to ask a *duplicate* question to have the issue revisited? What should I do to ensure the new question isn't just closed as a duplicate?

Comment: You could throw a bounty on the old question, but who knows how effective that would be. (Anyone know a SEDE query for *that*? [meta-tag:status-declined] -> bounty -> [meta-tag:status-completed])

Comment: Worth a shot. Here goes!

Comment: Maximum bounty of 500 puts it at the very bottom of the  Featured page. Hmm...

Comment: The Featured page is sorted chronologically. At the end of the 7 days, it'll be at the top, slowly working its way up there as older bounties drop off

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. Dang, 50 would have attracted the same amount of attention from the people who I actually want to see it. What a tragic waste of fake internet points.

Comment: "some guy who now works for the Dark Side"? He left to start another company.

Comment: @josh http://blog.codinghorror.com/civilized-discourse-construction-kit/

Comment: @gitignore why did you give Jeff the 500 points bounty?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Of the three choices (let the points disappear silently, give them to the only other answer, which wasn't helpful, or give them to Jeff) it seems like the most rational option. I'm sure the regular avenues of getting Jeff's attention (Twitter, email, blog, SE, Discourse) are flooded, but I bet it's not every day that someone randomly gifts him 500 of his own fake internet points.

Comment: an interesting example of a request that was reconsidered: [(4 years later) Dear Stack Exchange: can we change our site name?](http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7935/31260)

Comment: @mhlester a little late to the party, but according to [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/596423/questions-going-from-status-declined-to-status-completed-after-posting-a-boun) it happened 16 times so far.

Answer (score 15):

If you *just* want an existing proposal reconsidered, and have nothing to add, then no.

If you want to re-visit a topic, you should explain, in the question, what merits reconsideration.  You should explain what has changed since it was declined, why the problems no longer apply, why the benefits have increased, what *significant* considerations weren't considered before, etc.

Again its important to recognize that while feedback of a suggestion, in the form of votes, may well be considered by the dev team, popularity is not exactly near the top of the list of priorities for feature requests.  On the whole, most people don't actually understand the consequences of many of the suggestions they are voting on.

Comment: Thanks. I have a lot to add. Have for several years, but have had trouble getting anyone with authority to pay attention. See updates to the question.

Answer (score 2):

One option you have is to put a bounty on that question (since you have answered yourself, the minimum bounty is 100 reputation).

One of the standard bounty reasons is:

> **Current answers are outdated**
>
> The current answer(s) are out-of-date and require revision given recent changes.

That would apply to Jeff's answer in this case as an 'authoritative answer'. It might also motivate one of the devs to put in some extra work. (I do want to note that a previous 500 reputation bounty didn't work, so maybe no one is actually interested in implementing this. Just let it go then...)