# iOS: Add title to linked question in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown, ios-app, usability

When a question contains a link to another question, the question title is automatically inserted. For example, I'm going to paste a URL here:

[Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments)

Unfortunately, the same feature doesn't exist for comments in the iOS app.

It doesn't exist on the web version either, so why another request?

- Jeff declined the feature for comments because "comments are processed on the fly."[1][2] However, the system allows limited markdown syntax in comments. Why not automatically add the markdown formatting when the comment is entered?
- The iOS developers are smarter than the web developers.

[1] I went to the doctor and said, doctor it hurts when I do this. The doctor said "Don't do that!"

[2] That was years ago, so maybe it's no longer true that "comments are processed on the fly." Would be nice if someone in the know would tell us whether Jeff's answer is still valid.

Comment: +1 for instigating dev fights!