# Auto-title addition to comments

Tags: discussion, support

At one time, links pasted into comments benefited from automatic title "oneboxing," just as they currently do in posts.

Whatever happened to that?  Was there some sort of problem with it?  I personally find bare links in comments ugly, and generally fix them to include the title of the post I'm linking, but it's a lot of work (it requires a double copy/paste, and some deft use of brackets).

Comment: Are you sure this worked at one point in time? [I found a feature-request from 2011 talking about this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments)...

Comment: This has never happened, but you might have [had my script](http://stackapps.com/questions/2378/se-comment-link-helper).

Comment: Google recently put the kibosh on adding scripts from third-party sources. I sure wish that script was in the [Chrome Web Store](http://chrome.google.com/webstore).