# Is there some succinct markup to link to a post?

Tags: feature-request, comments, markdown

I love the [Beta site I participate in](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/) and I'm often the first one who invites the new users by commenting their posts, especially if their posts are somehow bad (e.g., q/no own research, q/too broad, a/citation needed, a/insufficient explanation, etc.)

I also *do* remember the ID's of the key Meta posts that discuss each individual problem. I'd like to have a possibility to post link to an individual post in my comment, like this:

`/q/42`, `//meta/q/42`, or maybe `[meta/q/42]`

I would prefer if I didn't need typing the domain name, as it suggested in answers to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254466/) or opening the post and sharing its link, as it suggested in answers to [this  question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45597/).

Is there any markdown template to do that?

It would be great if such markup worked both in my answers and comments.

Comment: You can always use the `[linktext](url)` pattern.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks, but that would not help the long `url`.

Comment: While `[meta]` expands to the meta url, typing `[meta]/a/6068` doesn't append the `/a/6068` to the link :(

Comment: I wouldn't have expected that to expand. I had an unreasonable expectation that I'd be able to fool the expansion ;)

Comment: I normally use the [Auto Comments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se) for that with sample comments from our repo:  https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/auto-comments