# Please automatically add the links from close-reasons into comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, close-reasons

Sometimes, a close-reason says it all, and while I also vote to close, I post the reason as a comment as well for faster feedback from new users.

Those close-reasons have some links for further reading for a reason though, so I suggest that if part of a comment, stripped of bold/italic/italic&bold-markers is identical to a close-reason, the site should add the links in automatically.

Comment: What's wrong with the banner? Aren't the links there sufficient?

Comment: I mean, if SE actually thinks that this is a problem worth solving, why have users copy-pasting the close reason in the first place, just have the system automatically show the close reason(s) for any pending close votes to the OP .

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ This is referring to when there are pending close votes, but the question isn't closed yet.

Comment: I doubt SE is going to go to the trouble of providing this functionality when they don't even support [automatic conversion of a link to a question to the title of that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments) in comments.

Comment: This could be done like with possible duplicate comments, that is the comments are posted automatically when a user votes to close and deleted automatically when the question is closed.