# Why is the auto-replace for on-site question-links with the respective question-title only enabled in posts but not in comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, hyperlinks

When you paste an url in a question or answer (i.e. a post), its link text is automatically replaced with the title of linked-to question, like so: [Replace trilogy raw links with the current question title?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49433/168610)

However, this is *not* done for comments. When you paste a link to a relevant question (perhaps even *only* the url) into the comment box, it will be displayed verbatim. This is especially tiresome for recurring c++-faq question-link comments. These questions have usually fairly well-curated titles that say enough on their own, but I have to Copy-Paste both the url and the title and manually `[Ctrl-V](Ctrl-V)` them.

What is the reason for this? Or am I using the interface wrong?

Comment: If there's nothing between the brackets or it has the default "enter link description here" message then this might be the cause for this, I dunno.

Comment: Jeff's [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86909/377214) to the declined feature request [Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77394/replace-links-with-the-current-question-title-in-comments) explains why it's not implemented for comments. I'm not sure if his rationale is still the case today, but that does explain why it was never implemented at first.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog Hm, I see. It doesn't seem to make much sense to me given that the assumption that the title lookup must be done at load time is just that, an assumption. The comment could be rewritten the instant you hit return and its plain text gets stored in the database. No more additional lookups in the future.

Comment: @bitmask In that case, though, if the linked title is edited, the comment will be forever broken. Anyway, that answers your question, which simply asks why it's not supported for comments.

Comment: @SonictheStay-HomeHedgehog How will it be forever broken? Particularly, why will be more broken than if I manually enter the `[title](url)` syntax? If the conversion happens automagically it leaves the possibility open to even update it later on. If I do it manually, however, this becomes much harder.

Comment: If you are using Firefox then [Copy as Markdown – Get this Extension for  Firefox (en-GB)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/copy-as-markdown/) will (when right clicking a link) can put `[Link Content](url)` on the clipboard for you ready to paste into a comment. Eg using this question it generates `[Why is the auto-replace for on-site question-links with the respective question-title only enabled in posts but not in comments? \[duplicate\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348608/why-is-the-auto-replace-for-on-site-question-links-with-the-respective-question)`

Comment: Which appears as [Why is the auto-replace for on-site question-links with the respective question-title only enabled in posts but not in comments? \[duplicate\]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348608/why-is-the-auto-replace-for-on-site-question-links-with-the-respective-question)

Comment: For Chrome, [Copy As Markdown - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-as-markdown/dgoenpnkphkichnohepecnmpmihnabdg?hl=en) does something very similar (I have not tested this).