# Is there a reason not to enable replacing internal SE URL text on comments with the page linked to?

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks, internal-links

On *[Super User](https://superuser.com/tour)*, I looked for a Linux proportional font terminal, and found *[OS X or X11 terminal emulator supporting proportional fonts](https://superuser.com/questions/563502/os-x-or-x11-terminal-emulator-supporting-proportional-fonts)*, in which the accepted answer suggested a Mac port of Emacs, but it did not explain how to use Emacs as a proportional font terminal.

I posted a followup question about how to get Emacs to enable the functionality which was migrated to *[Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tour)* at *[How can I use Emacs under Linux Mint as a proportional font Evil-mode editor and a proportional-font terminal?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80572/how-can-i-use-emacs-under-linux-mint-as-a-proportional-font-evil-mode-editor-and)*. After upvoting and accepting an answer, I added a breadcrumb comment on the original post's answer, which I was hoping would display with the title.

Instead of displaying the title, it displayed an abbreviation of the URL to the latter link above: `For a followup question about how to get Emacs to display the requested behavior, see emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/80572/….`

Could the behavior in a question body of displaying internal URLs by a question title instead of the raw URL also be enabled in comments?

Comment: There is this (status-declined) feature request from 2011. Most of the [posts linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/77394) seem to be about the same thing.

Comment: Here's an explicit link to the post mentioned by Martin in the previous comment: [Replace links with the current question title in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77394)