# Error with non-whitespace-separated anchors in comments

Tags: bug, comments

When putting a comment, [I tried to create a link for each letter of a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10028670/mysql-find-events-that-occured-x-times-during-given-period/#comment-13093821). The anchors were created with error - see comment below. The code of the comment is the same as this block (it apparently works in posts):

> the comment was: try searching "group by time(stamp) interval", it will yield you [m](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7992252)[a](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7571740)[n](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4342370)[y](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6884207)[y](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4342370)[y](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3086386) [results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=group+by+timestamp+interval) :-)

Putting spaces between letters fixes the problem.

Comment: the comment was: try searching "group by time(stamp) interval", it will yield you [m](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7992252)[a](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7571740)[n](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4342370)[y](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6884207)[y](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4342370)[y](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3086386) [results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=group+by+timestamp+interval)

Comment: Just link once to the search, its more "useful" (for very lax definitions of useful).

Comment: @Mat, I linked the search once.

Comment: I can't get past the "why *should* we support this?" phase of this bug report...

Comment: I agree with @NickCraver. I would almost consider this a feature rather than a bug.

Answer (score 1):

[Nick is right.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129568/error-with-non-whitespace-separated-anchors-in-comments#comment354744_129568)

This is an inconsequential <sub><sup>[bug](/questions/tagged/bug)</sup></sub>, IMO. Tell me one *good* reason for having to have multiple links in one word. Linking every letter in a word is not a *good* reason, it's just [fun](/questions/tagged/fun). And, unfortunately, [we hate fun](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/) ;-)

Why do we need anchor text?

For one, they [make links legible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/41473/178438). The more important thing it, others(i.e. anyone to whom the comment isn't directed) can understand what the link is pointing to without having to open it. For example, in this post itself, most readers will recognize the "we hate fun" link above without having to open it.

A similar case would be when you have a comment akin to `[Javascript has a strange scope]--use var, it [goes in local scope]. A [forin] loop is [always a bad idea in such cases]. Would you like to try [jquery]?`. Most users will be able to guess the content behind these links and won't need to click.

I don't see how `[m][a][n][y][y]` does anything like this. It's hard to even tell that it's five different links at a single glance. Then, the link text tells you nothing.

A better way to comment would be: `try searching "group by time(stamp) interval", it will yield you many results: http://stackoverflow.com/... http://stackoverflow.com/... http://stackoverflow.com/... http://stackoverflow.com/... http://stackoverflow.com/... http://stackoverflow.com/...`