# Add anchors to the user pages

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, hyperlinks, anchor

Would be nice in many cases to link directly to every section in a user page one wants to point out.

For instance, in discussions on upvote/downvote ratios, users that are outliers are sometimes called out, and it would be nice to have a link such as

https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis#votes

That would go directly to the upvote/downvote section.  Sections that would be useful are:

info
questions (already named)
answers (already named)
votes
tags
badges

Comment: So that we can discuss users' voting habits in excruciating detail?

Answer (score 1):

Eh, why not... I like anchors. Always bugs me when sites don't use enough of them. MSDN is terrible about this; W3C is great (guess that kinda makes sense though).

Kevin Vermeer dug up [this awesome suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts) which you should all go and up-vote now.

Comment: Someone find that suggestion for me and I'll upvote it too!

Comment: @Shog9 - It's here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37894 but it's got a cogent argument to not allow anchors in long answers: If the answers spill to two pages, the link may break (similar to the old argument against comment anchors).

Comment: Thanks @Kevin - the solution here is easier than for comments, since answer links already contain the answer's ID (and thus can load the correct page) - the trick is simply to generate the IDs (and links containing them) automatically so as not to lose this information.

Comment: @Shog9 - Ah, so [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50734) is no longer a problem?  That's what the latter half of my comment is referencing...I miss being able to edit comments after the fact.

Comment: @Kevin: yeah, [check out the format for comment links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment/120688#120688) - the trick is that the answer ID always stays part of the path (so the site knows to send down the page with the right answer) and then a bit of script handles the rest. In-answer targets wouldn't require the script.