# PostType = Wiki, Wiki + Reputation can it be done?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, community-wiki

I would like to propose a new PostType to the tetralogy. PostType = Wiki.

#### What should be Wiki?

I think the ideal candidates for wiki style posts would be posts that are **long** and **already are community wiki**.

For example this query captures quite a few of them: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/66

#### What is different about Wiki posts?

- Wiki posts are owned by the community.
- You can gain reputation by improving Wiki posts.
- Wiki posts do not fit the current Q&A model, the question is the title, the answer is the body.
- Wiki posts only have commenting, there is no answering allowed.
- Wiki posts have a special UI
- Wiki posts have search priority (maybe)

#### OK, give some examples

[List of freely available programming books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books) is a wonderful post with lots of information, the trouble is, there is no incentive to keep it up to date. **And** the answers, well they are noisy and a repeat of what is at the top.

One more is [Git for beginners](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=git+for+beginners). The big trouble is that you need a page reload every time you want to navigate to a section. And scroll-up foo.

Another [C++ for a C# developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285723/c-for-a-c-developer/285819#285819). It's really useful information that would cover probably a few hundred questions and really is a community effort.

The seminal [Hidden Features of C#?](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=hidden+feature+of+c%23) would by amazing if it was just a single document with collapsible sections. After you work through 2 of them you just get tired of refreshing your web browser.

This one, [The .NET SDK Programs - What does each tool do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362687/the-net-sdk-programs-what-does-each-tool-do/2176970#2176970), fits the wiki mold so tightly it's scary. It's a perfect candidate.

#### Other ideas around post type wiki

- Wikis could be used for some static pages on the site like [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq).
- On meta we could use a wiki for the long requested change log
- If we allow an abstract for wikis (8 lines of so) they could be [associated with a tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/create-a-tag-homepage-faq) and show up in the box when a tag is selected.

So:

1. Do we need this kind of post?
2. What are the mechanics involved in building this?

Comment: I think you just wrapped every feature-request into this one post around the wiki thing :)

Comment: Would give me more stuff to do.

Comment: none of this stuff is what our sites are really about. As you said "Wiki posts do not fit the current Q&A model". I only see it happening at the [tag] level as we coalesce [tag] level FAQs and info.

Comment: also these are *terrible* questions you're using as examples. Yes they have a lot of content, but the presentation is just.. noise. This is not what our sites are about.

Comment: Humm, This question should be a community wiki then..

Answer (score 10):

I'll be the (so far) lone dissenter and upvote the idea. Putting my Meta Internet Dollars at massive risk here, just so you know!

Why do I like the idea? SuperUser. Wha-wha-wha?! Yes. I recently discovered that [one of my questions](https://superuser.com/questions/133764/can-i-use-an-nvidia-geforce-9600gt-for-triple-monitor-closed) on SU was closed as an exact duplicate by random. At first I thought, hey, they're not dupes! The tech involved is different!

Then I realized why it was closed -- SU would be overrun by the phenomenon of a million super-similar-but-different-only-in-a-single-technology questions if mods weren't diligent. (And thank you for your diligence, mods, particularly in the land of Ewoks.)

As this dawned on me, I was thankful that the question was closed, but felt a little empty: **How could the community address scenarios like this, where a million similar-but-just-slightly-different questions could come up?**

I think your idea, waffles, could handle that scenario. And thus, I support the idea. Either that, or one master community wiki post in the current framework with answers for specific technologies. But I think your idea, if the ability to [include named anchors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts) were included, would probably be more effective. (And would provide accurate dupe fodder for those questions.)

Comment: They could address it by coalescing common FAQs to the tag page, as in my answer. Supporting random "true" wiki questions isn't going to happen. ever.

Comment: @Jeff: I wouldn't expect any of the discussions on SOFU to become 'true' wiki questions or topics. One of the characteristics that define an idea like this, the way I see it, is more like an archive. There are many, many topics that have worn their welcome (not that I wouldn't want to re-read all the 'Skeet-isms') - CW items that have traveled their journey should be moved to a repository. I think it would be like cleaning up the classroom and building a reading room addition. Please forgive my poeticism...

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, this is closely related to the

[Create a tag homepage/FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/create-a-tag-homepage-faq)

proposal.

I don't see us doing this except as a [tag] page feature. The focus of the sites is not to be a host of epically large FAQ questions, but a host of related questions around a topic.

The natural place to coalesce the common elements of the topics is in the parent [tag] page which is the natural home for that "topic"  anyway.

> Wiki posts do not fit the current Q&A model, the question is the title, the answer is the body.

.. which is why they're a bad fit. We do Q&A. There can be some wiki-ness around the [tag] parent but that's about it.

Comment: I always thought "tag homepages" would be little things like a paragraph or two. not "large FAQs"

Answer (score 4):

This is a good idea, but I am not convinced that it is possible to combine wiki with reputation without becoming too complicated or open to abuse. I think that people will contribute without reputation incentives just to reduce the number of duplicate questions or because they want these resources for themselves.

Comment: +1 @ Casebash: I would be concerned about gaining rep as well. I think that some may be appropriate...but such a small amount that it is obviously not because of the rep that contributions are made. Should only be a token thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Aarobot. There is *something* here. Great idea waffles. I see a huge difference in this idea of a SOFU-wiki than the typical wiki-pedia.

1. the wiki is produced by the SOFU community. Not only are the items brought up from questions that have been wiki-fied, but a huge source of information follows. A lot of it is very valuable information that I would guess is actually fairly untapped.
2. the Wiki is moderated by 6K+ *(or whatever)* users ensuring that all information is maintained - adding new information and editing.
3. a more dynamic, digital tome of vast amounts of diverse technical information and data.

Well, these are just a few ideas on why it is a good idea. This idea for a wiki just doesn't have the same feel as a wiki-pedia site would. I really think that it can be done in such a way that it isn't just another wiki.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297577/is-there-a-perfect-algorithm-for-chess) is an example of a good discussion to wiki-fy.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Meh, too many implementation details and complications for very little gain in my opinion.</strike>

(post kept here for historical purposes. I withdraw this opinion though)

Comment: Try googling this http://www.google.com.au/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=git+beginner lots of traffic comes in here, it would be nice to have a better page to present that info