# Is there an analysis of what % of total site pageviews comes from users with a certain amount of rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation, users, statistics, data-analysis

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75581/is-everyone-in-favor-of-the-new-everyone-can-edit-idea-is-this-really-such-a-g) got me curious: What percentage of total page-views of the site are from users with editing privileges?

Whether that information is truly important or not is debatable, but it shows how this data could be useful. It would be really cool to see what percentage of page-views come from:

- users as opposed to non-users (1 rep)
- users with editing privileges (2k rep)
- 10k users

I can see a variety of situations where this info would be interesting. :D

Comment: @Mrozek are you trying to prove that more users should have editing privileges? :D thanks

Answer (score 7):

Ran a couple of queries, and it looks like ~5% of our daily visitors* (over estimating this, for sure, but its kind of noisy data so... yeah) have any reputation.

Less than 1% have edit permissions, and less than 1/10th of a percent have 10k rep.

Essentially, it's still (and has always been) true that the vast (vast) majority of SO "users" are not registered.

<sub>*Visitors != page views, but I can get better numbers for that metric.  Even if you assume the typical registered users visits orders of magnitudes more pages than an unregistered one, the lion's share of page views still go to unregistered users.</sub>