# Question views / site visit ratio of anonymous versus authenticated users

Tags: discussion, statistics, traffic

Just a question out of curiosity: StackOverflow has around 4M unique visits per day (https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com). Have they ever published numbers on what ratio of traffic is anonymous versus authenticated users?

Specifically is there any information on:

1. % of those unique visits which are authenticated users?
2. ## question views per authenticated user versus non authenticated users?

Comment: Hmm, I recall Shog posting something on that. Now if only I could find that.

Comment: [There is this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75601/161198) but that might be outdated by now. I expect the percentages to be lower.

Comment: I am glad it took you at least a few minutes to find - I *did* try and find an answer before posting...