# Why are other users allowed to approve third party edits?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits

A while back I answered a question and another user recently made a factually incorrect edit to my answer. The edit was approved by a third user, and my post was altered. I was able to reject the edit, but how is this allowed to happen without singular confirmation of the edit from the original poster?

In my opinion, what I write is my voice and my reputation. Any additional information, arguments, or refutations should be added via comment, not via editing a post or comment. If it's an inappropriate post or answer, then it should be deleted.

I feel like there are people roaming around just looking for things to edit frivolously to earn points, and it's irritating that this behavior is actually incentivised.

I suggest at least an option to opt-out of third party edit approvals.

Comment: You're notified of the edit suggestion and you're able to roll it back... I don't really see the problem.

Comment: @SonicWizard This is a FR, specifically asking to create an opt-out. It's valuable related info but it doesn't relate to the FR.

Comment: @Catija According to the FAQ on duplicates, "a feature request that goes against one of the ideals/principles of Stack Exchange may be closed as a duplicate of a question that explains that principle."

Comment: The why is probably better answered by the question [Is everyone in favor of the new “everyone can edit” idea? Is this really such a good idea?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75581/323179), which was asked when suggested edits were first introduced.

Comment: The wrong answer was live for like a month. Anyone can edit is fine, but an opt-in for me being the final point of approval is a different feature request.

Comment: @JaySpeidell When my post was edited I received a notification so I could review. Didn't you get one?

Comment: @Jay you are already the "final point of approval". You, as post author, can approve or decline pending edit with single vote, and even reject an already approved edit. That's really more than enough.

Comment: Note that since April last year you're able to [override community reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/295028/295232) as the author of a post.

Answer (score 5):

To a large extent, we 'farm' out a lot of moderation tasks to the community.

In theory the idea behind suggested edits is to let new users get used to edits, with certain restrictions like a minimum number of characters and review.

That said, a lot of the 'design' of edits is designed to give the poster the final say. So, if its a crappy edit, you probably got told there was an edit, and can roll it back. I wouldn't overdo it, and rollback/edit wars can get ugly.

*Experienced* users with sufficient reputation can do their own edits. Suggested edits are kind of meant for new users to do reviews that are overseen by more experienced users. Who...sometimes fail to do the right thing. Some folks just click accept, some folks just want the badges without the actual effort.

So, just roll it back. If you catch the edit first, reject. Its totally cool.

In theory there's tools to reduce bogus accepts, like review audits, but at the end of the day, you can always go over the edits, and cherry pick (or not) the bits you need.

Comment: Would it make sense to not give points for the review of edits, or cap edits at a few per day or even stop giving points after 5 per day or so? This would de-incentivize volume.

Comment: maybe but we actually want new users to get into the habit. I'd actually put more of the blame on the reviewers *but* once again, you can always roll back. I don't remember off hand if that undoes the edit reputation tho

Comment: @JaySpeidell Authors can override the edit approvals and revoke the +2 for the suggested edits if they like. Also, we already have mechanisms to stop unnecessary edits: users can earn up to 200 reputation from post upvotes **and** suggested edits and up to a maximum total of 1,000 reputation from approved suggested edits.