# Add anchors to the how-to-ask and how-to-answer pages

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, anchor

Often, when I cite the [How to Ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) or [How to Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) pages, I'm mostly pointing out one particular paragraph (usually “Provide context for links”). So I'd like to write `[please summarize the contents of your link](http://SITE/how-to-answer#link)`.

Please add anchors to the “How to Ask” and “How to Answer” pages.

Comment: May be the page need some more spaces on lower part to get anchors correctly work when someone clicked through those?

Comment: Or is there a better, more specific page in the FAQ somewhere to link to?

Comment: Related: [Support anchor names in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts)

Comment: Related: [Linking to subheaders of a help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322237/335251) (These 2 requests are basically a subset of that one as well: [Can we have anchors for the bullets in the \[help/on-topic\] list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300028/335251) – and a corresponding request on MSO: [Add anchors to enable direct linking to detailed reason on "What topics can I ask about here?" page and others](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360239/1478931))

Comment: Also related: [Linking to subheaders of a help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322237/335251)

Answer (score 5):

It's been a little over 4 years since [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40356/163250) to [the post that @Shog9 linked-to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89440/add-anchors-to-the-how-to-ask-and-how-to-answer-pages#comment731983_89440) was last-edited. I don't know if adding functionality to the Markdown parser to transform text to anchor names/ids is what's holding the implementation of this up, but if it is, even just hard-coding in anchor names/ids for the sub-sections of just the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) help pages would be really, well, helpful ;)