# Add discoverable anchor links to the FAQ

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, site-faq, anchor

I wanted to post a comment with a link to a particular piece in the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) and it seems there is no way to link to say "What is reputation?" or "How do I ask questions here?" parts of the FAQ.

I think it would be great if those questions were linkable, and obviously so without having to view the source to know that the anchor exists.

**an idea**

right now the source looks like this

```
<h2>
    What kind of questions should I <i>not</i> ask here?</h2>
<a name="dontask"></a>
```

what if it where changed to

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask" name="dontask"><h2>
    What kind of questions should I <i>not</i> ask here?</h2></a>
```

Comment: There are anchors on the Stack Overflow FAQ, only they're not glaringly obvious.  You have to view the source just to be able to see them.

Comment: that's good to know, will modify my question then

Comment: How would you do this?  Add a cute little anchor icon with the link to that section?

Comment: @Won't see my edit

Comment: @Won't: presumably the same way that you click the `link`, uh, link below questions and answers to bring up a pre-filled text-input to copy the URL from? Preferably with the same 'link' text for the purpose of consistency within the site.

Comment: @Won't: [exactly](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2009/12/show-anchors-bookmarklet.html). [As long as the anchors exist, that is.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89440/add-anchors-to-the-how-to-ask-and-how-to-answer-pages)

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for the scriptlet :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a way to do this with the new, improved FAQ -- each section has obvious link areas and a place to copy the link to that subsection of the FAQ.