# Linking to subheaders of a help center page

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, help-center, anchor

Could we add the ability to link to subheaders in a site's help center? Sometimes it would be nice to be able to reference a specific part of a page so one's audience doesn't have to search around.

Suffixing the url using `#name` would probably be the clearest way to implement it since it is already a common way websites do it.

Or, if this is more of a upstream Markdown issue, I guess it would make sense to mark this question as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined)...

Or alternatively, if linking to subsections is already possible, I would be very curious to learn how.

Comment: Related: [Can we have anchors for the bullets in the help/on-topic list?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300028/295232)

Comment: Also related: [Add anchors to the how-to-ask and how-to-answer pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89440/add-anchors-to-the-how-to-ask-and-how-to-answer-pages?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: @Glorfindel *Very* related. Almost duplicates, but those questions are about more specific solutions, while mine poses a more general non-implementation specific question. Although I wouldn't be terribly unhappy if this was marked as a duplicate of the second question you linked.

Comment: Also related: [Support anchor names in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37894/335251)