# Add anchors to privilege pages

Tags: feature-request, privileges, help-center, anchor

Now and then I want to support a Meta answer with a link to information about a certain privilege from the [Help Center](/help/privileges). However, some detail pages are actually about a *group* of related privileges and have become quite long.

It would be useful to be able link directly to e.g. the 'Access moderator tools' section on the [10k page](/help/privileges/moderator-tools), e.g. with https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools#access-moderator-tools. There are no elements with IDs in the content, so all I can do is link to the page itself and hope the reader will scroll down.

A nice bonus would be if those anchors would be presented as links on top, similar to how the new [Public Terms of Service page](/legal/terms-of-service/public) has been designed.

Note that the [Markdown Editing Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) has a similar structure already (though technically it's not part of the Help Center).

Comment: The content on these pages are actually built just like [question pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSw8Z.png), so they're written in MarkDown... which doesn't have anchors. I think we'd have to convert them to CSS and full HTML (which is already the case for some pages like the [markdown page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help), ironically) but it wouldn't be editable by CMs and would require a code change if we were to need to edit it in the future... :(

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, good to know this. It might be possible to write it only partially in HTML, if I use `<h2>Access moderator tools</h2>` in my question it works too. The HTML-to-markdown converter, which for mere mortals like me doesn't support the `id` attribute in `h2` tags, could be made a little more intelligent for you and your colleagues.

Comment: Related: [Linking to subheaders of a help center page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322237/335251) – It might make sense to close this as a duplicate of that request, since that one's a broader request about adding anchors on Help Center pages in general (which isn't currently possible).