# Under what conditions are notifications about expiring of bounties sent?

Tags: support, bounties, notifications, email, global-inbox

As far as I can tell, a user who offered a bounty receives several notifications of this type.

- Your bounty on question "... expires in three days.
- Your bounty on question "... expires in one day.
- Your bounty on question "..." is completed. You must award it to an answer within 24 hours.

For example, a screenshot of one such notification is shown in this question: [Improve bounty notification "You must award it to an answer within 24 hours." when there are no answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348053).
These notifications are mentioned in this answer to [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post: [What events trigger an inbox notification?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319353#319354)

At the same time a [comment under that post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319353/what-events-trigger-an-inbox-notification/319354#comment1046567_319354) mentions that such notifications are not sent always.

> Update: after deeper inspection, looks like the inbox notification appears only when **there are answers that you can give the bounty to.** Still need to test to be 100% sure then we can edit it into the answer. :)

[Another comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319353/what-events-trigger-an-inbox-notification/319354#comment1046565_319354) also mentions a notification by email

> The "bounty expiring soon" was a notification sent when grace period starts, you also get email with title "Bounty Grace Period Started". The email is still being sent (got one today) however there is no longer inbox notification. Might be a bug though.

Aside of those comments, I did not manage a find a place where this is clearly documented. (And the linked comment does not sound entirely conclusive.)

**Question:** What conditions decide whether the notifications about bounties (to the global inbox and by email) are sent?

- Are they sent only if the question has at least one answer?
- Does it matter whether the answer was posted before or after the start of the bounty?
- Are there some other conditions, or does this depend only on the existence of an answer?