# Anchor links for sharing specific answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, hyperlinks, sharing

I want to be able to share answers using anchor links, such that when the link is visited, the page scrolls to the particular answer instead of showing the top of the page.

A good example is seen with this [link](https://developer.github.com/changes/2018-10-18-github-api-development-and-support/).

Comment: Doesn't each answer have a share link?  Sharing that is an anchor to that post.

Comment: Oh yh, the problem was from my end. I tried elsewhere and it works just as I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just click the 'share' link below the answer. It will do exactly what you want, in the browser but even in the Stack Exchange mobile apps.

For example, [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19499/295232) (`https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19499/295232`) goes directly to the Jon Skeet meme answer, not to the question.

It's *not* possible to link to a *specific place* in an answer (or question), see [Support anchor names in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/37894/295232)

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks.