# Allow linking to named anchors

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks

This is similar to [Support anchor names in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts), but I don't think it's a dupe. Markdown should support links that are just named anchors, like `[foo](#12345)`. I occasionally reference existing answers in comments or my own answers if I'm expanding on them, and currently I need to include the full URL to get Markdown to link it, which seems unnecessary. Just copying the answer's link is annoying because it's a different URL, so when users click it it loads a new page, even though it's actually the exact same page. To get around it I tend to take the current URL and splice in the `#id` of the answer I'm linking to, but Markdown should assume that if I just include the `#id` part

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What if the your answer or the answer you cross-referenced to get pushed to page 2? Then the link is broken.

Comment: Good point, I forgot there even were pages

Comment: But how can we reference certain comments?

Comment: Couldn't the comment system just expand the link by hand to fix that issue?

Comment: @Michael plus, for more problems with tweaking the links, this is already linked in the right column: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58645/please-make-links-to-other-answers-in-the-same-question-link-to-the-anchor-instea

Comment: @Cawas It was also asked two months later

Comment: @Michael no argue there! I'm also pointing out more info to anyone who might stumble upon here and get interested, since you're not! ;-)