# Make a link to another answer in the same question without reloading

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, permalink, anchor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please make links to other answers in the same question link to the anchor instead of the full URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58645/please-make-links-to-other-answers-in-the-same-question-link-to-the-anchor-instea)

### Proposed Solution

Same idea from the duplicate, but less words and a suggestion:

Use jquery. RegEx scan all links on the current question that are pointing to itself and on the same page, if it has more than 1, and the js will just `scrollto` the anchor if clicking on the link.

### Introduction to the Issue

In HTML this is simply solved using `<a name="anchor">` and `<a href="#anchor">`. Obviously the anchor is already set there, but how to use it? There are actually many issues in using the anchor that way, as listed on the other question.

### Example of the Issue

[What would you use to zero pad a number in Flex/AS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666531/what-would-you-use-to-zero-pad-a-number-in-flex-as3/6377321#6377321)

There I've linked the other answer, but if you click on it it will reload the page while it didn't need to. And if you click on "Phil's" after falling on the [question the most common way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666531/what-would-you-use-to-zero-pad-a-number-in-flex-as3), same issue. I've tried tweaking the URL, but also couldn't do it. I sure could have tweaked it to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666531/what-would-you-use-to-zero-pad-a-number-in-flex-as3#669310` but that also wouldn't work at all cases anyway.

Comment: Haha, @Brandon... I identify myself a bit with Evan Carroll, wonders a duplicate would come from him. I think I wouldn't be much different from him if I were born in Texas! :P

Comment: Yep, I believe it's essentially the same thing. Plus there's some deeper analysis there. So, looks like this is still unsolved after all, huh? Though this is much less cluttered and an answer here can be accepted, while there it can't. >:)

Comment: It would be a great idea, and not that hard to implement.  I guess you should throw a bounty on Evan's question (I contributed an upvote to you to help out with that).

Comment: I suppose technically it's `[status-declined]`, since hash-only URLs are not allowed intentionally now. If they were allowed, there's no guarantee that the answer would be on the same page that the link was, so it's much more error-prone than just using the full URL. Still, I suppose it's something that might be beneficial to add to the [SE Modifications](http://stackapps.com/q/2138) userscript...hm.

Comment: @Lance are you by any chance talking about the jquery idea I suggested on Evan's? Should I propose an edit there and expose it better to add the bounty first, or should I edit here?

Comment: @Tim it wasn't a `[feature-request]`, and there's actually at least 1 technical way I could think of to still implement something with jquery, as I mentioned! ;)

Comment: @Cawas, I just meant the idea of having the links change to be the in-page type.  I would think that the markup processor would handle it, just like it now handles other hyperlink changes, but I'm not hung up on how it happens.  It's just obvious that SO is already changing links anyways, so they can do in that case too, and it will cut down down on both client and server load.

Comment: @Cawas The linked question is a feature request though, which is what I was basically referring to. I know that you can do it, I just don't imagine it'll happen since it has a very limited use case.

Comment: @Cawas, I just left an answer on the original.

Comment: @Lance I'm up for adding a bounty anyway, never thought any of this would be a be a good enough feature-request to generate interest in anyone! But I'm still wondering how it'd be best to do it. Well, now you did it I'm even more lost!

Comment: @Lance there. edited the question and did the bounty. let's see now. :P

Comment: @Cawas, great, hopefully it gets a little more play.

Comment: How do you propose that this should work if there are many answers and the target and original are not on the same page of result in some views?

Comment: @dmckee since pages are server side and there's no ajax on it yet, there's not much that can be done in that case. the jquery should simply not be added on those.

Comment: @Lance There was no more play there! :( oh well...

Comment: @Cawas, yeh, guess you're right, though it being Evan's post might have had something to do with it.  Thanks for trying.