# A link to each answer at the top - Feature Request

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, anchor

I would like to propose putting link pointers to each answer at the start of the answers section. This would be in the style of a contents page.

By looking at the link description, one can directly head into the required answer, suppose a question like `nginx php config types` might have more than one answer like `php.conf` as well as `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`... which can be shown as different links, and user can choose what they wish to look at.

In questions with many answers, this feature will be useful to quickly move to the most promising answer.

**ADDED - As asked by commentors - this is somewhat what I am thinking of...**
*question and the answer labels don't relate, but I am pasting a general style*
[image]
**ANSWERS**
[image]

Comment: I don't see how this would be useful - seeing as a link can not convey whether the answer is actually a good one or not? What text would the links have?

Comment: it is not like if the answer is good or bad... but look at some questions which have got many answers may be like pure css, using jquery, using plain javascript... etc.

Comment: The `share` link on an answer will take you directly to the answer already.

Comment: I think a comment would let your thought heard. downvoting will not.

Comment: what share link @oded ?

Comment: Can you show what the links would look like? All I can think of is something like `Answer 1` `Answer 2` etc. and I don't see how having a list of those is more helpful than just seeing the answers as it is now.

Comment: @sivatumma - the share link under each and every answer.

Comment: yes... let us take a question where the questioner asks a solution for a style... may also question mentions they are struggling with old browsers that do not support much of scripting... If the starting answers are written in jquery, javascript, css3, html5, media queries etc, then assume a person have written an answer in PURE CSS, which would rather wont be visible. and if there are upvotes for starting answers (which the questioner wont be finding useful, ) then ? in those scenarios, a link called `PURE CSS` would definitely help the questioner and the subsequent visitors.

Comment: @Oded I think [that's what the OP is after](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58645/please-make-links-to-other-answers-in-the-same-question-link-to-the-anchor-inste). (voting to close)

Comment: that was linking to other pages. I am thinking of clear visibility of answers in the same page, for a question on current page...

Comment: @ShadowWizard My reading of this was that of a "contents page" at the beginning of the answer section. But it must admit I am a little unclear at present

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't think that's what he means. It sounds like he wants a kind of navigation at the top of the answers section.

Comment: @RichardTingle  - you got my request - clearly. contents section in the start of the answers section.

Comment: @RichardTingle (and Stijn if you see it) might be, without mockup it's really hard to tell though.

Comment: @Pëkka did you atleast understand the request ? And the downvoters I think are just out of finger wrestling games they don't know where they are clicking...

Comment: @sivatumma I've edited to make it a little clearer. Feel free to roll back if my edit doesn't describe your request properly

Comment: @sivatumma The downvotes will be for 2 reasons; "unclear", or just because they disagree that this will be a useful feature. Be aware that voting on meta is different. Votes can be of the normal form but can also simply be disagreeing with the idea. I personally [don’t like this system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182028/220332) and would be in favour of a change to [separate voting for the idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116010/agree-disagree-button-on-meta-or-upvote-downvote-effects-based-on-tags) but that is the current system.

Comment: @sivatumma I would imagine it looking something like this; http://imgur.com/Z3ossEL

Comment: wonderful. I also made some _hardwork_. Please find the question edit. But where did you find that style ??

Comment: @sivatumma I made it in Paint.Net (a bit like photoshop but free)

Comment: Completely impossible to summarize answers with those short little links you've demonstrated.

Comment: This is not a dupe of the question that closers are attempting to close it for.

Comment: Not every question has answers where the situation is as clear as in your example (so that there's one jQuery approach, and one JavaScript approach, etc.) In a way, to correctly label an answer, you'd have to know *every other answer* in advance.  It's an interesting idea, but I don't think it can be implemented in a reasonable way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Support anchor names in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts)

Answer (score 4):

This is impractical.

If there's only one answer, what's the point?

If there's dozens of answers, how is this useful? Especially when answers may be on a second page.

Don't forget, either, that answers can be sorted a number of ways. How do you sort the links?

At most, an anchor link to the top of the answers ("jump to answers") might be useful, but only if it's a long question and/or has a lot of comments.

So, I see very little utility for this.

Comment: The only way I would see this being useful is if each answer had a title as well and the title of the answer was displayed in the list

Comment: exactly - If not little of the answer, the answerer would be clearly stating what the answer is about - what is their answer's importance. And coming to single answer questions, I need not tell you how many you find like that and how many you find multiple answered questions.

Comment: @sivatumma So would each answer be given a title under your request? Is so I'll do a little more editing

Comment: Ugh. People have enough trouble writing question titles. Writing answer titles?

Comment: Well @AlE., I agree. But my idea is to enforce (slowly habituate) clarity while writing answers. I thought this is really a gap filling feature in the SO

Comment: But we've been struggling for five years to get people to write good titles, and failed. Adding yet *another* point of failure is unlikely to improve the site - and arguably, just one bad answer title would break the entire concept's usefulness.

Answer (score 1):

With the majority of questions there is only really one answer (thats how we like it). Therefore all the titles will basically be the same as the question title (or more likely something worse).

However I was able to find a question where it would work (possibly because the question was a little too broad) and were this to be implemented here is a mockup of how I would do it

[image]

Comment: This answer cleverly comes down on both sides and is therefore sure to enrage everyone

Answer (score 0):

This loses practicality on questions where there really aren't too many diverse ways of going about something. Sure, you could theoretically have "With angular do this ... with jQuery do this .. with plain JS just do this ..." but that's probably a sign of a very poorly scoped question.

Even on canonical questions, there tends to usually be only one - or at most several - answers to a question once everything is condensed. In cases where this *would* be beneficial, you could simply insert it into the bottom of the question using existing markup, similar to this:

---

- [Using jQuery and unicorn tears](http://example.org)
- [Plain Javascript implementation](http://example.org)
- [You should drop that and try CoffeeScript](http://example.org)

---

But again, this only becomes useful if you're drawing attention to posts that might otherwise be overlooked, which means that we're dealing with pages of answers, which almost *always* means something is very wrong with the question.

Declining, because I just don't see the payback justifying the additional complexity of answer titles, and codifying support for questions that sort of go off the rails. It's not a horrible idea, it just doesn't fit our model too well - anywhere that this becomes useful is probably an area deserving of quite a bit of editorial attention and cleanup.

Comment: Correct. I thought of reading this so like a book. So that it will be more perfect to look. And I also think of votes being visible for these linked headings. Just like as you mentioned, I thought of a script that automatically puts this detail in the start of the answers sections (automated editor). Probably with 0 overhead for additional fields. This is minor though. I somehow think that this scenario needed for at least 10% of the SO.