# How to add a hyperlink to some <a name="foo"> on current page?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow linking to named anchors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50731/allow-linking-to-named-anchors)

How can I add a hyperlink to some `<a name="foo">` on current page?

The page link is

```
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31863/blabla
```

One answer on that page has link

```
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31863/blabla#31985
```

I want to refer to that answer, and try to add a hyperlink as

```
[that anwser](#31985)
```

Sadly it doesn't work until I change it to

```
[that anwser](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31863/blabla#31985)
```

But the latter one need to reload the whole page.

So what should I write to make a hyperlink to a `<a name="31985">`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't. The Markdown only matches to links that begin with `http://` or `ftp://` (I think those are the only two) so there's no way you could use a same-page ID marker. Any link not matching merely gets removed.