# With CommonMark, will named anchor tags be supported?

Tags: discussion, markdown

I figured this had been asked by now, but I guess not, or maybe I didn't find it when I was searching.

I commonly want to provide anchor links in answers (esp. when creating footnotes), but SO flavored Markdown has a whitelist of allowed tags and that's never supported the `name` attribute of the `a` tag before, so I've been unable to use `#name` to directly link to a footnote.

The [switch to CommonMark](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark) obviously means a pretty significant change in the Markdown rendering engine, so will the current whitelist of pure HTML remain as it is or will things be changing around with that and if they're changing, will this restriction be relaxed?

Similar questions have definitely been asked in the past (e.g. [Allow linking to named anchors](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50731/allow-linking-to-named-anchors?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Support anchor names in posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37894/support-anchor-names-in-posts/40356#40356)) but none since the switch.

Comment: Does CommonMark has a spec for named anchor tags? One of the challenges that remains is keeping those names/ids unique on a single page when a question and several answers can now introduce ids/names.

Comment: @rene not as far as I'm aware. It also doesn't have tables but people seem convinced we should implement them. :(

Comment: @Catija yeah, I checked the specs 6 to  8 months ago for anchor id support and only found an item in the issue list and a lengthy discussion. None of that seemed close to be ready for a spec, let alone implementation. Haven't checked back later, hence my comment.

Comment: @rene The difficulty of conflicting `names` is definitely real, although it'd be worth seeing how much of an issue it actually is in practice. I'm not so much asking about the named anchors in done in _Markdown_, since that seems to be a huge can of worms, but rather named anchors as done in _raw HTML_ (i.e. as `<a name=...>...</a>`).

Comment: @rene yeah, I've been poking around at their Discourse since I stumbled across it. To be fully transparent, we definitely have markdown that's non-standard still... easiest example is spoilers. We're supporting it moving forward but, eventually, if it gets implemented, we'll have to migrate to the standard (assuming they don't just use ours, which is a possibility).

Comment: To keep them unique on the page, it's reasonable to just prepend all of the anchors in a post with the post's ID (e.g. `349076-some-special-section`).

Comment: [No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark#comment1166935_348746), not right away anyway. Existing FR: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89314/332043