# URLs to link to a particular comment, and other SO elements?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Direct Link to a Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment)

Do we have a list of URLs to target specific SO elements in a page -- an answer, a specific comment, etc. -- and info about how to go about retrieving the ids for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments are given an HTML id which you can link to.  However, you have to use your browser's tools (e.g. "inspect page") to find it, and no commitment from the site that they won't change (but I find that unlikely).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120688/153020

Answer (score 1):

You have a permalink for the answers, just click on the link button, or right-click and copy.

Comment: [None for comments?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42236/#comment-104529)

Comment: Yes, for comments ,for example: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42236/#comment-104529

Comment: @Gnome, thanks, glad they added that.