# User feed contains comment entries with duplicate IDs

Tags: bug, status-completed, feed

The user feed (on StackOverflow and Meta at least) contains entries for comments which have IDs that aren't unique.

A quick example (picked at random): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/131779

Looking at one specific question (42601), the feed contains 1 answer, 2 comments on the question itself, and 1 comment on the user's own answer. The question comments have the same ID (the URL with no fragment), and the answer and its comment have the same ID (the URL with ID in fragment).

Having duplicate IDs causes some (primitive/strict) parsers to drop some of the entries. Presumably comments need to have some kind of ID tacked onto the end of the URL to ensure the IDs are unique.

URLs/IDs in full (sans domain):

- question comments: /questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting
- answer + comment: /questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting/42604#42604

Comment: That's the wrong user.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, we are going with this URL format for comments:

```
<id>http://example.com/questions/1234/title/5678?cid=9999#5678</id>
<id>http://example.com/questions/1234/title/?cid=9999</id>
```

Purely for the purposes of disambiguation in the RSS feeds, only -- these aren't functional links.

I see no need, ever, to [deep link to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment)...