# Does the user feed actually link to comments?

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks, feed

On the [activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) of a user you can see user feed. This feed seems to include also comments - however, those links are in a strange format. I can just say that when I try them, they do not link to comments.

I will use [my own feed as an example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/183484).

For example, I can see there the following two links to comments:

```
    <entry>
        <id>https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271268?cid=1055531#271268</id>
        <title type="text">Comment by Martin on A guide to moderating chat</title>
...
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271268#271268" />
...
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <id>https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117569/how-can-i-bookmark-a-chat/117571?cid=1055001#117571</id>
...
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117569/how-can-i-bookmark-a-chat/117571#117571" />
...
    </entry>
```

However, when I try the links given there, they do not actually lead to a comment, as you can check for yourself.

The links from the first entry are: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271268?cid=1055531#271268` [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271268?cid=1055531#271268) and
`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271268#271268` [A guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271268#271268) It is probably supposed to be link to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271268#comment1055531_271268).

The links from the second entry are:
`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117569/how-can-i-bookmark-a-chat/117571?cid=1055001#117571` [How can I bookmark a chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117569/how-can-i-bookmark-a-chat/117571?cid=1055001#117571)
and
`https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117569/how-can-i-bookmark-a-chat/117571#117571` [How can I bookmark a chat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117569/how-can-i-bookmark-a-chat/117571#117571) It is probably supposed to be link to [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117569/how-can-i-bookmark-a-chat/117571#comment1055001_117571)

In both cases the number shown as `cid=Id` (such as `117571?cid=1055001#117571`) seems to be the id of a comment. However, in the URL that actually link to a comment this number appears in a different format in the URL (`117571#comment1055001_117571`).

---

I have also tried to post a feed [into a chatroom](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/1303/2019/1/26) - also there it seems to pick *posts* rather than *comments.*

I will mention also the fact that the tooltip shown when hovering over the "user feed" link says: "feed of the 30 latest questions, answers, and comments from this users". This suggests that the intention was to include comments.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This older post seems related: [User feed contains comment entries with duplicate IDs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/42617#44117).