# How to Get a Comment's URL?

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Direct Link to a Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment)

I propose that there be a non-painful mechanism to refer to a particular comment in a post with a URL; right now it's pretty hard to do that.

(By non-painful, I mean something other than viewing the page source and finding the comment URL.)

Comment: Just copy the link on the timestamp of the comment

Comment: @Barry: Wait, what? I right-clicked the `9 secs ago` next to your comment here, and I don't see any "Copy Link" thing...

Comment: @Barry is probably already using one of the scripts that provide this functionality and forgot it :)

Comment: We don't want you linking to comments. Comments are temporal; they can be deleted or hidden at any time, breaking your links. There's no button exposed for this for a reason.

Comment: @Cody: Isn't the same true with questions (for < 10k users anyway)?

Comment: @balpha: Yeah my bad.  I have a few scripts installed and totally forgot that the functionality wasn't built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the perfect place for a userscript.  For each `id` element in a `tr` tag, add a little link icon with the URL set to the page, #, and the `id` string inside the `tr` body.

Comment: Idk any JavaScript. D: I'm just beginning to learn CSS...

Comment: @Mehrdad: my http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76720/userscript-for-comment-permalink-support-closed provides this, and this functionality is also part of http://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-an