# Permalink Comments?

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Direct Link to a Comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment)

There should be a way to permalink comments, too. I found a comment that answered my question better than the answer (because it was specific to my problem, not that it was a real answer) and I wanted to link to it, but I can't. Sometimes, comments are great and they should be able to be permalinked. Shouldn't be too hard. [URL]#id.

Comment: It's all well and good that this was closed as a duplicate, but why did I lose points? I looked for duplicates. The other one was labeled funny. He called it "Direct Link to a Comment." Instead of "Permalink Comments." Most people on this site know what a permalink is and StackOverflow didn't suggest it as a similar article. I read through that list for a while and didn't see it. Yet I lose reputation?

Comment: Direct comment links exist but should be more intuitive, e.g. having permalink icon - see
[Improve the usability/intuitiveness of direct comment links](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280567)

Comment: I asked this question five years ago. I actually think my asking this question made it happen.

Answer (score 3):

Questions and answers are entities of their own, but comments are comments to either a question or an answer - linking to a comment without context does't sound right to me.

---

Update:

Comments [can now be permalinked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5436/direct-link-to-a-comment) - the link is the timestamp on the comment.

Comment: I can't accept this answer as THE answer, but I'd love to upvote you for the salient point you make. Alas, I don't have the required 15 rep. So at least know that your comment wasn't made in vain, my dear Oded, and that I appreciate your response. It may take a long time for me to get enough rep to upvote you, friend, for I am not popular on Meta as I question the system and the moderators around here sure do get butthurt easily. I'm sure I'll be reprimanded/have my comment edited/deleted.

Comment: @vbullinger - Things change. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113240/permalink-comments/113241#comment334883_113241) is the link to your last comment.

Comment: Came back to this question now that I have enough reputation to upvote you, @Oded :D

And, yeah, I wonder if my suggestion was taken...