# Add chat oneboxing support for comment links

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, chat, onebox

Since we have [direct links to comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/120688/156727) now, IMHO it would only be fair for comment links in the chat to be treated on the same level as question and answer links.

(This question feels kinda empty, and I don't even have a pony picture handy to pad it...)

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/2518132#2518132

Comment: I think that pony has a jgs stuck in its hair.

Comment: [FYI](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=850260#850260).

Comment: Retagging since nobody seems to believe what I said in chat :) /cc @Tim

Comment: This *should* now be there... just figuring out what cog fell off...

Comment: @MarcGravell - it appears to be working now.

Comment: ah, might be working for answers... fixing for questions

Comment: Sweet! <forthechars />

Comment: Dammit, what did I get wrong! Goes back to the IDE...

Comment: @MarcGravell They both seem fine, although the format is kind of strange (I would think putting the comment's score and "C: Post Title" for the title would be more consistent)

Comment: @MarcGravell - it just worked for me on both questions and answers.

Comment: @ChrisF where? I'm in the chat.meta.SO sandbox room, and nada...

Comment: @ChrisF can haz example?

Comment: @MarcGravell - head over to the Teachers Lounge

Comment: @MarcGravell It's working for questions, but not answers over here.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ can you show me an example where it isn't working?

Comment: @MarcGravell Try http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126922/what-does-se-use-to-calculate-reputations-sql-aggregate-functions-a-manual-met/126942#comment344727_126942

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ all fixed now

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Done and done (including some last-minute fixes for some different url constructions)

Comment: FYI, it works for me (question and answer comments): http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/922854#922854

Comment: The onebox of the comment displays the questions / answers votes instead of the comment's vote itself. I believe this is a bug..

Comment: @jokerdino actually it was intentional, to use a consistent format and not be confusing what the number was, since it is adjacent to the post title. We could *additionally* add the comment score, maybe?

Comment: I think adding both the posts and comments' score would be information overload. I can live with how it currently is.

Comment: [The chat formatting faq](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting) still says that just "Stack Exchange questions,
answers, and users" can be oneboxed

Comment: @AakashM true - in addition to comments, we also don't call out "sites". Will review.