# Make oneboxing work for comments in chat

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, chat, onebox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Add chat oneboxing support for comment links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121001/add-chat-oneboxing-support-for-comment-links)

As the title says, now that comments are linkable, I would like them to be oneboxed to appear similar to [this one](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=1988309#1988309), when they are linked in the chat.

Comment: I like the idea; especially since links to comments are natively supported now and don't require a userscript.

Comment: Well, unlike a post, a comment's length has roughly the same restrictions as the chat message's length...

Comment: @GraceNote: I have found that some comments do not fit, though. I'm not sure about the actual char numbers, though.

Comment: @GraceNote Chat messages themselves can be oneboxed, and they can't be longer than chat messages.

Comment: @sbi Chat is limited to 600 chars, but keep in mind that the `>` prefix, and the signature and timestamp, both take up characters that are not included in the comment's 600 chars.