# Tags should onebox

Tags: feature-request, tags, chat, onebox

Tags should onebox. I suggest those be simply triggered by writing the tag name between brackets. The output would be something like:

> **[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)** 51k questions, 11k followers.
>
> C is a general-purpose computer programming language used for operating systems, games and other high performance work and is clearly distinct from C++. It was developed in 1972 by Dennis Ritchie for use with the Unix operating system. [Read more.](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info)

Comment: You can already put the tag name in brackets to get a link to it; why would you want a whole onebox?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Perhaps so they can see all the tag wiki goodness that's been added to the tags as a result of the closing of certain NC questions =P

Comment: The bit about comment oneboxing is a duplicate at least [twice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121001/add-chat-oneboxing-support-for-comment-links) [over](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122250/make-oneboxing-work-for-comments-in-chat). :P I have the same question that Michael does about the tag oneboxing, though.

Comment: @TimStone: TCO.