# Broken comment links on review page lead to nowhere

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, hyperlinks, comment-links

Comment links on review pages, whether questions or answers, do not link to the original comment, but link instead to the comment as it is on the review page.

[image]

Clicking on a comment's timestamp will take you to that comment, but only while you're on that page. Using that link after leaving that page, or giving it to someone else, just takes you to review the first post on the unreviewed list for that category. Is this really the intended behavior?

Comment: ..and yes, I know that links to comments are [2nd class](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/27319/168660) [citizens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44119/168660), but if you're gonna do it, do it _right_.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome. That said, I have no idea why you'd click on the timestamp to view a comment on the /review page.

Comment: @TheEstablishment Came across an interesting comment while reviewing that I wanted to link to. IAE, if there's going to be link at all, let it make sense.

Comment: ...IAE? [Googling seemed to be of no help](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAE).

Comment: @TheEstablishment IAE = [in any event](http://www.abbreviations.com/term/260760)

Comment: Probably just an unintended consequence. They just recently added those comment link things (couple months now?), so they probably just forgot about the review panel. I'm sure they'll fix it.

Comment: If a page offers permalinks to comments, they should be accurate links. There are many reasons you might want to capture a comment's permalink when you find it on a review page. You might, for example, be discussing in a chatroom or with other moderators and wish to supply context by pasting the link.

Comment: This is still occurring in the new review panel.

Comment: @Emmett, This has 15 votes, and 3 duplicate questions were asked. That's better than most bugs or behavior requests. How is this too localized?

Comment: @HodofHod I was cleaning up old, outstanding bugs that applied to the *old* review system (i.e. no longer applicable). In most cases, I just deleted the question. But if the question had considerable upvotes/comments, I just closed it for posterity's sake. If I misinterpreted this question, or you'd rather it be handled differently, let me know.

Comment: @Emmett Ah. This is still happening in the new review system, as mentioned here in the comments, and in at least 1 of the duplicates. I'll edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the comment link code to ensure that comment links outside of the question page actually go to the question page.

With you in the next build.