# wrong permalinks for comments on English.SE review page

Tags: bug, permalink

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment links on review page lead to nowhere, when they exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132407/comment-links-on-review-page-lead-to-nowhere-when-they-exist)

On the English.SE review page, when comments are displayed, their permalinks are wrong (different, and don't work). For example:

(from review page)
[<sub>`https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/12114#comment180650_90344`</sub>](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/12114#comment180650_90344)

(from question page)
[<sub>`https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90344/used-to-or-used-for#comment180650_90344`</sub>](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90344/used-to-or-used-for#comment180650_90344)