# Broken comment links in the Review Close Votes queue

Tags: bug, comments, review, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comment links on review page lead to nowhere, when they exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132407/comment-links-on-review-page-lead-to-nowhere-when-they-exist)

Sample review item with a couple comments: https://english.stackexchange.com/review/close/13016.

The comment links are all of the form

```
<site>/review/close/<current review item ID>#<comment ID>
```

Clicking on any of them takes me to a different review item from the queue. I would have expected them to be of the form

```
<site>/questions/<question ID>/#<comment ID>
```

which would actually take me to the corresponding comment so I can upvote it or fix the formatting (I can't do either in the review queue).

Comment: Well, the anchor has `href="#<comment ID>"` so the link is relative to the current page.

Comment: @Sha yes, and it shouldn't be. Neither should a link relative to the current page load a different page. That's not really relative to the current page, like, at all.